# Show only specific lines and an area in one legend with ggplot2

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, legend

I have a question concerning a certain plot. Consider I have the following data.frame:

```
data <- data.frame(a = c(44, 58, 60, 63, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70), 
               b = c(38, 52, 55, 57, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 65),
               c = c(51, 64, 66, 68, 70, 71, 71, 73, 74, 75),
               d = c(44, 53, 54, 55, 56, 56, 58, 59, 59, 60),
               e = c(44, 57, 59, 60, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67),
               x = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10))
rownames(data) = c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J')
```

I want to plot the three polygons (x,a), (x,d), (x,e) with the three different linetypes 'solid', 'dotdash' and 'dash'. They should all appear in the legend. Besides I want to plot the polygons (x,b), (x,c) with linetype 'dotted' and color the are between them red. Only the red area should be displayed in the legend but not the dotted lines themselves. To do so I wrote the following code lines:

```
data_no_legend = data[,c(2,3,6)]
data_legend = data[,c(1,4,5,6)]

data_melt_legend = melt(data_legend, id = "x")
data_melt_no_legend = melt(data_no_legend, id = "x")

p <- ggplot()
p <- p + geom_ribbon(data = data, aes(x = x, ymin = b, ymax = c,fill = 'legend'), alpha = 0.5, show.legend = TRUE, inherit.aes = FALSE)
p <- p + scale_fill_manual(labels = c("legend"), values = c('red'))
p <- p + geom_line(data = data_melt_legend, aes(x = x, y = value,    size = variable, linetype= variable), color = 'gray', show.legend = TRUE,  inherit.aes=FALSE)
p <- p + scale_linetype_manual(labels = c("legend 1","legend 2", "legend 3"),values = c("solid","dashed", "dotdash"))
p <- p + scale_size_manual(labels = c("legend 1","legend 2", "legend 3"),values = c(1,0.5,0.5))
p <- p + geom_line(data = data_melt_no_legend, aes(x = x, y = value,  group= variable), color= 'gray', linetype = 'dotted', show.legend = FALSE,  inherit.aes=FALSE)
p <- p + geom_point(data=data, aes(x = x, y = a), color = 'gray',  size = 1.5,inherit.aes=FALSE)
```

Unfortunately I have two different legends. One for the lines and one for the area. Can anyone help me out? Thank you!

Comment: I think you missed a 9 in your `x` column. Also, `data_melt_index` and `data_melt_no_index` are nowhere to be found. Do you mean `data_melt_legend` and `data_melt_no_legend` respectively?

Comment: So is your question about removing the "fill" legend, or are you trying to combine it with the line legend? In the latter case, do you want it to just add a fourth key, or to do you want "legend 1", "legend 2", and "legend 3" to all have the color as the background?

Comment: I want to combine it with the line legend and just add the colored area as a fourth key.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, this took a bit of doing, but I think this works. I am generating a new column named "Legend" that should show what you are trying to display in the legend itself (so, you will likely want to updated it). Note that I am using `gather` from `tidyverse` instead of `melt` and using `mutate` from `dplyr` to generate this data format.

The trick is that you then need to set a linetype that includes the values for which you want to have lines from `geom_line`. I set the size to 0 to avoid double printing of the line. Then, you add your line and set the aesthetics you want to print. The final trick is to use `override.aes` to change the fill color behind the lines (essentially, adding it for the `geom_ribbon` group) and suppressing the separate legend for the fills (if you use `show.legend = FALSE`, it won't let you set a fill for the `linetype` legend either).

```
gatheredData <-
  data %>%
  gather(variable, value, -x) %>%
  mutate(Legend = ifelse(variable %in% c("b","c")
                         , "bc", variable)
         , Legend = factor(Legend
                           , levels = c("a", "d", "e", "bc")))

ggplot() +
  geom_ribbon(aes(x = x
                  , ymax = c
                  , ymin = b
                  , fill = "bc"
                  , linetype = factor("bc"
                                      , levels = levels(gatheredData$Legend))
                  )
              , data = data
              , size = 0) +
  geom_line(aes(x = x
                , y = value
                , linetype = Legend
                , group = variable)
            , gatheredData) +
  scale_linetype_manual(values = c(a ='solid'
                                   , d = 'dotdash'
                                   , e = 'dashed'
                                   , bc = 'dotted')
                        , name = "Legend"
                        , breaks = levels(gatheredData$Legend)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c(bc = 'red')
                    , drop = FALSE) +
  guides(
    linetype = guide_legend(override.aes = list(fill = c("gray", "gray", "gray", "red")))
    ,    fill = "none"
    )
```

gives

[image]

Note that I used the legend levels to set the order of the legend entries. It is really finicky for some reason, and required me to explicitly set `breaks =`.